# Gitlab-runner installation

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed gitlab and docker in Ubuntu. Now I need to install gitlab-runner using docker executor. Is it necessary for the gitlab to be running in docker or is it enough if both runs on the same machine?

Comment: You can install gitlab runner on any machine that can communicate with your gitlab server they don't need to be on the same machine. it easier  to run it in docker but not required.

Answer (score 0):

- GitLab Runner is the open source project that is used to run your jobs and send the results back to GitLab. So it just needs connectivity to Gilab and its done by registering the runner. [Registering runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/)
- Registering a Runner is the process that binds the Runner with a GitLab instance.
- If you want to use Docker, GitLab Runner requires a minimum of Docker v1.13.0.
- Allows to run:

  - Multiple jobs concurrently.
  - Use multiple tokens with multiple server (even per-project).
  - Limit number of concurrent jobs per-token.
- Jobs can be run:

  - Locally.
  - Using Docker containers.
  - Using Docker containers and executing job over SSH.
  - Using Docker containers with autoscaling on different clouds and virtualization hypervisors.
  - Connecting to remote SSH server.
- The GitLab Runner version should be in sync with the GitLab version,  features may be not available or work properly if there’s a version difference.